# mtrace accuracy

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a plugin for a daemon, and right now I am in the last stages. So I've thought of `mtrace` to look for memory leaks, as I don't see any possible way of starting a `valgrind` instance (I am not running the actual daemon, I run a starter process which checks some config files, and after that starts the daemon).

So, as I am looking through the logs from `mtrace`, I see a lot of very inaccurate info. For example it says that `index += UNIT` is a memory alloc that is never freed, and a lot of similar stuff.

I am running the following command for `mtrace`:

`mtrace ./a.out memory > raw.log; cat raw.log | tr -s " " " " | cut -d" " -f4 > err.log; cat err.log | addr2line -e a.out > fin.log`

Any ideas on why I get the totally not useful output?

P.S.: a.out is compiled with all the debug flags on

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with `addr2line`.
You should try to read the original `raw.log` and see if it makes sense.
Take one suspicious allocation, find it in the raw log, run `objdump -lrd a.out` and find the assembly line. It should be a call to `malloc`. If it is the fault is with `addr2line`, if it isn't, the fault is with `mtrace`.

Some possible pitfalls:
1. Compiling `a.out` without `-g`.
2. Running one `a.out` and giving another `a.out` to `addr2line`.
3. Searching for the line number you got in an incorrect version of the source.

P.S. You don't have something like `#define UNIT (malloc(1000),7)`, do you?